# C# namespace not recognized by C++ via COM

Tags: c++, com

I currently have a C# class library as such

```
namespace Library
{
    [ComVisible(true), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("aa950e58-7c6e-4818-8fc9-adecbc7a8f14")]
    public interface IQuote
    {
               ........
    }

}
```

I then register it using the following

```
RegAsm.exe C:\MyFile.dll /tlb:MyFile.tlb /codebase
```

Now the problem in my C++ application is that

```
#import "c:\\MyFile.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
using namespace Library;
```

and then I get the message

```
Error   7   error C2653: 'Library' : is not a class or namespace name
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Library is a very general word, and may have specual meaning somewhere. Have you tried a different name with the same setup?

Comment: Crack open the generated .tlh and .tli files in your Debug/Release folders and see what namespace is being used (if any). It might not be what you think it is.

Comment: Let me check the tlh and tli files

Comment: I have change the location of output file to c:\ and the only file generated is .tlb

Comment: I tried doing OLE/COM Object viewer for tlb it has something like library OptionFeed
{.......}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COM itself does not have a concept of namespace (which is language-specific).

RegAsm.exe uses the assembly name as the name of the library statement in the IDL. It does not care which namespace your COMVisible class is in.

By default the C++ compiler imports a type library into a namespace with its name specified by the library statement in the IDL. Use the assembly name as the namespace name (or rename the namespace in the import statement) in your C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

Took 2 hours, to figure this out.

Sample code is here:

```
#import "path\to\MyLibrary.tlb"      // DEFAULT assembly name  is  namespace
namespace MyNameSpace = MyLibrary;   // make alias back to your namespace

MyNameSpace::IMyClass1Ptr obj;       // use namespace here
obj.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MyNameSpace::MyClass1));  // access class in my namespace
```

Hope that helps.